# writing a data.frame using cat

Tags: r, dataframe, cat

How can I add/append data.frame abc to the text file that I have opened previously. I am writing some important information to that file and then I want to append that data.frame below that information. I get an error when I try to write the data.frame abc using cat.

```
fileConn<-file("metadata.txt","w+")
smoke <- matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
smoke <- as.data.frame(smoke)
table <- sapply (smoke, class)
abc <- data.frame(nm = names(smoke), cl = sapply(unname(smoke), class))
cat("some imp info","\n", file=fileConn)
cat(abc,"\n", file=fileConn)
close(fileConn)
class(abc)
```

Comment: `capture.output(abc, file = fileConn)` would work, too

Comment: @lukeA it works. Please add it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 4):

Just use the standard tools for writing `data.frame`'s, i.e. `write.table`:

```
write.table(abc, 'yourfile', append=TRUE) # plus whatever additional params
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
capture.output(abc, file = fileConn)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the output is readable, you could use also `knitr::kable()`. This will print your table as character, which has the advantage that you can embed it directly within the `cat()` call. It has lso several printing options (`digits`, `align`, `row.names`) etc that make it easy to control for how your table is printed:

```r
tab <- knitr::kable(head(swiss))

cat("This is my file:",
    "Some important note about it",
    tab,
    sep="\n")
#> This is my file:
#> Some important note about it
#> |             | Fertility| Agriculture| Examination| Education| Catholic| Infant.Mortality|
#> |:------------|---------:|-----------:|-----------:|---------:|--------:|----------------:|
#> |Courtelary   |      80.2|        17.0|          15|        12|     9.96|             22.2|
#> |Delemont     |      83.1|        45.1|           6|         9|    84.84|             22.2|
#> |Franches-Mnt |      92.5|        39.7|           5|         5|    93.40|             20.2|
#> |Moutier      |      85.8|        36.5|          12|         7|    33.77|             20.3|
#> |Neuveville   |      76.9|        43.5|          17|        15|     5.16|             20.6|
#> |Porrentruy   |      76.1|        35.3|           9|         7|    90.57|             26.6|
```