# How to write a header vector plus dataframe using cat()

Tags: r, dataframe, io, cat

Similar: [writing a data.frame using cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511282/writing-a-data-frame-using-cat) however this is about appending to a file, I want to write a new file.

I have a header, and a dataframe which I want to write to a file using cat():

```
header <- "This is the top row,\n
           where the values are:"

df <- data.frame(val1= runif(3), val2 = runif(3))

# Write to file
cat(header, df, 
    file = "path/to/file.txt", 
    sep = "\n")
```

Gives an error:

```
Error in cat(header, df, file = "path/to/file.txt", sep = "\n") : 
  argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

It says list, but class(df) shows that it is a dataframe, and I have made this dataframe basically the same way as above.

How would I print it so it would look something like this (df separated by any sort of whitespace):

file.txt:

```
This is the top row
where the values are:
0.63138 0.70402 
0.50136 0.61327
0.10447 0.26874
...
```

The full file can go up to a dataframe of 101 lines.

Comment: data frames are implemented internally as lists, the elements of the list are column vectors

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cat` with `write.table`.

```
header <- "This is the top row,\n where the header info is.\n"

cat(header, file = 'file.txt')
write.table(df, 'file.txt', append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a crack:

```
cat(
  paste0(
    header, 
    paste0(
      trimws(
        gsub(
          "^\\d+", 
          "", 
          capture.output(
            print(
              df
              )
            )
          ), 
        "left"), 
      collapse = "\n")
    ),
file = "path/to/file.txt", 
sep = "\n")
```

Data:

```
header <- "This is the top row, \n where the header info is.\n\n"

df <- data.frame(val1= runif(3), val2 = runif(3))
```

Comment: This almost works, except I don't want the row numbers and column names in front of each line, just the values

Comment: It works for the first 10 instances, but any rownumber above 10 doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`kable` can format the data frame and return a vector that `cat` can write to a file. It can also do the desired rounding and alignment.

```
library(knitr)

# store the header text as a vector for better spacing
header <- c("This is the top row",
            "where the header info is.")

df <- data.frame(val1= runif(3), val2 = runif(3))

# convert the data frame into a simple  markdown text table
text <- kable(df, digits = 5, format = "simple", col.names = NULL)

# remove the extra markdown formatting 
text <- text[!grepl("---", text)]

# write to your file
cat(header, text, sep = "\n", file = "path/to/file.txt")
```

The result will contain

```
This is the top row,
where the header info is.
 0.23796   0.20287
 0.67260   0.41703
 0.53092   0.26330
```

Comment: This works best so far, only I don't want the header names there. Just the values. But this was fixed with text[c(-1,-2)] instead of text[-2]

Comment: Adding the `col.names = NULL` option to the `kable()` function call is another way to remove the column names. I'll updated the post to remove them