# Convert image in to data frame in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tesseract

I want convert the image in to data frame. I am able to read the image and make it a character object.

```
library(tesseract)
eng1 <- tesseract("eng")
text1 <- tesseract::ocr("image.png", engine = eng1)
cat(text1)

class(text1) #character
```

```
head(text1)
[1] "* teamiD ~ yearlD ~~ NumsP_ TGS oplayerID Gx GS Wx > Lx ERAX\n\n1 ANA 1997 11162 finlecnot 12 23 ca 8 452\n2 ANA 1997 11162 langsma0t 162 2 ae 8 452\n3 ANA 1997 11162 perismant 162 8 ae 8 452\n4 ANA 1997 11162 cieksja01 162 32 ae 8 452\n5 ANA 1997 11162 hasegshot 162 7 ae 8 452\n6 ANA 1997 11162 sprindeot 162 8 ae 8 452\n7 ANA 1997 11162, mayda02 162 2 ae 8 452\n8 ANA 1997 1162 ilkeot 12 2 ae 8 452\n9 ANA 1997 11162 grosskeot 162 3 ae 8 452\n10 ANA 1997 11162 gubiemao1 162 2 ae 8 452\n11 ANA 1997 11162 watsoalot 12 Be ae 8 452\n12 ANA 1998 2162 sparksto 162 2 8 7 449\n13, ANA 1998 9 162 cicksja0t 162 18 8 7 449\n14. ANA 1998 9162 alivaomot 12 26 85 7 449\n15. ANA 1998 9162 finlecnot 12 Be 85 7 449\n16 ANA 1998 9162 washbja0t 162 1\" 8 7 449\n47 ANA 1998 9162 watsoalot 12 4 85 7 449\n18 ANA 1998 9162 medowja0t 162 14 8 7 449\n"
```

[image: data frame]

I need the data in **data frame** that this image show.

Comment: You need to provide the head of text1

Comment: Im put the image data. So, Im upload with head()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ocr` is not a faithful representation of your image, and you risk garbage in/garbage out, but `text1` can be sequentially cleaned to eventually be in a data.frame:

```
text1_a <- gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', text1)
test1_b <- gsub('(11)', '\\1 ', text1_a)
test1_c <- gsub('(91{1})', '\\1 ', test1_b)
test1_d <- gsub('(21{1})', '\\1 ', test1_c)
read.table(text=test1_d, col.names=c('teamID', 'yearID', 'NumSP', 'TGS','playerID', 'G.x', 'GS', 'W.x', 'L.x', 'ERA.x'))
   teamID yearID NumSP TGS  playerID G.x GS W.x L.x ERA.x
1     ANA   1997    11 162 finlecnot  12 23  ca   8   452
2     ANA   1997    11 162 langsma0t 162  2  ae   8   452
3     ANA   1997    11 162 perismant 162  8  ae   8   452
4     ANA   1997    11 162 cieksja01 162 32  ae   8   452
5     ANA   1997    11 162 hasegshot 162  7  ae   8   452
6     ANA   1997    11 162 sprindeot 162  8  ae   8   452
7     ANA   1997    11 162   mayda02 162  2  ae   8   452
8     ANA   1997    11  62    ilkeot  12  2  ae   8   452
9     ANA   1997    11 162 grosskeot 162  3  ae   8   452
10    ANA   1997    11 162 gubiemao1 162  2  ae   8   452
11    ANA   1997    11 162 watsoalot  12 Be  ae   8   452
12    ANA   1998    21  62  sparksto 162  2   8   7   449
13    ANA   1998     9 162 cicksja0t 162 18   8   7   449
14    ANA   1998    91  62 alivaomot  12 26  85   7   449
15    ANA   1998    91  62 finlecnot  12 Be  85   7   449
16    ANA   1998    91  62 washbja0t 162  1   8   7   449
47    ANA   1998    91  62 watsoalot  12  4  85   7   449
18    ANA   1998    91  62 medowja0t 162 14   8   7   449
```

The main challenge here is to arrive at consistent number of columns per row, and much of the `ocr` garbage remains, with a little more added in, but is a data.frame.

Just using the setting described in [weird data](https://bookdown.org/markhoff/css/working-with-weird-data-an-example.html), I get the following improvements in `ocr` after image cleaning with `magick`, here just from downloading your embedded image above:

```
team_img <- image_read("team_data_WrCDj.png")

> team_mgk <- team_img %>%
+ image_resize('2000x') %>%
+ image_convert(type = 'Grayscale') %>%
+ image_trim(fuzz = 40) %>%
+ image_write(format = 'png', density = '300x300') %>%
+ tesseract::ocr()
> cat(team_mgk)
~ teamID yearlD NumSP TGS playerID G.x GS W.x Lx ERA.x

1 ANA 1997 11 162 finlechO1 162 25 eB 78 4.52
2 ANA 1997 11 162 langsma01 162 9 fond 78 4.52
3 ANA 1997 11 162 perisma0t 162 8 & 78 4.52
4 ANA 1997 11 162 dicksja01 162 32 & 78 4.52
5 ANA 1997 1 162 hasegsh01 162 7 & 78 4.52
6 ANA 1997 11 162 sprinded1 162 28 & 78 4.52
7 ANA 1997 11 162 maydad2 162 2 & 78 4.52
8 ANA 1997 1 162 hillkeO1 162 12 & 78 4.52
9 ANA 1997 11 162 grosske01 162 3 & 78 4.52
10 ANA 1997 11 162 gubicmad1 162 2 4 78 4.52
11. ANA 1997 11 162 watsoal01 162 is & 78 4.52
12 ANA 1998 9 162 sparkst01 162 20 65 77 4.49
13, ANA 1998 9 162 dicksja01 162 18 65 7 4.49
14 ANA 1998 9 162 olivaom01 162 26 65 7 4.49
15 ANA 1998 9 162 finlechO1 162 34 65 7 4.49
16 ANA 1998 9 162 washbja01 162 11 65 7 4.49
17 ANA 1998 9 162 watsoal01 162 14 65 7 4.49
18 ANA 1998 9 162 mcdowja01 162 14 65 77 4.49
```

So, still some GS, W.x, L.x problems, but things are improving. I think you'll become much more of an expert at `magick` through this process. And with better image, none of the above `regex` approach is necessary...

Comment: This is exactly the thing that I need.

Comment: It is essentially fragile and needs to be tuned to what your `ocr`(s) return, but this is a kind of approach. I did a lot of try this, try that, and what remains still needs to be played with to bring it back to the actual data...

Comment: In GS and W.x  show different values but maybe is for the `ocr ` return like you said. Some ideas for make better this, other library?

Comment: I think our package universe for `ocr` is `tesseract` and `magick`. I forward this [weird data](https://bookdown.org/markhoff/css/working-with-weird-data-an-example.html) to suggest perhaps the 'image' needs some cleaning prior to `ocr`, as covered toward the bottom, and maybe this is the way forward...`playerID` can be adjusted (ends with 01) via regex. In W.x, the transition point from 84 to 85 at row 12 is picked up, but the ocr results otherwise are inconsistent. So, image cleaning prior to ocr? And I imagine this is the only form of data you have available so has to be solved.

Comment: Data wrangling at it's best.

Comment: What is the process used to acquire the images?

Comment: Best settings so far on `magick`, image_resize('2500x') %>% image_convert(type='Grayscale') %>% image_trim(fuzz=20) %>% image_write density='600x600', localizes errors to W.x column. You'll still want to `<-  gsub('\\.', '', team_mgk2)`, put them back in for ERA.x, after you've written cat out to file [cat 2 file 2 df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511282/writing-a-data-frame-using-cat).

Comment: Im take the photo by screenshot. The idea is learn how to transform this situation in a data frame.

Comment: Broadly, the above steps, in different combinations, seem like they will get you there, and once you 'dial in' the best settings, magick and tesseract will accept lists of images.