# write a data.frame to an R file

Tags: r, dataframe, cat

I wish to write a `data.frame` from one `R` file to another `R` file using `base R`.  So far I have tried `cat`, `capture.output`, `write.table` and `sink`.  I found suggested solutions for `capture.output` and `write.table` here:

[writing a data.frame using cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511282/writing-a-data-frame-using-cat)

However, I have not been able to obtain an ideal solution.  `write.table` comes the closest but returns an unwanted `warning` message.

Here is the `data.frame` in the source `R` file:

```
my.df <- data.frame(scenario  = 3333,
                    AA        = 200,
                    BB        = 999,
                    CC        = 444,
                    DD        = 7)
```

Here is the desired appearance in the recipient `R` file except I want the name to be `my.df`, not `desired.format`:

```
desired.format <- read.table(text = '
             scenario    AA    BB   CC  DD
                 3333   200   999  444   7
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here is the full code for the source `R` file except for the `setwd()` statement:

```
R.file <- 'my_R_file.R'

cat(' '                                            , file = R.file, sep=c("\n")               )
cat('This is my stuff'                             , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)
cat('#'                                            , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)
cat(' '                                            , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)

my.df <- data.frame(scenario  = 3333,
                    AA        = 200,
                    BB        = 999,
                    CC        = 444,
                    DD        = 7)
str(my.df)

# Desired format in my_R_file.R
desired.format <- read.table(text = '
             scenario    AA    BB   CC  DD
                 3333   200   999  444   7
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(desired.format)

# capture.output includes an unwanted row number
cat(' '                                            , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)
cat('capture.output'                               , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)
capture.output(my.df, file = R.file, append = TRUE)
cat(' '                                            , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)

# write.table returns an unwanted warning message
cat('write.table'                                  , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)
cat('my.df <- read.table(text = \''                , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)
write.table(my.df, file = R.file, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, append=TRUE)
cat('\', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)' , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)
cat(' '                                            , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)

# sink does not return any useful output
#cat('sink'                                        , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)
#sink(R.file)
#sink()
#my.df
#sink()
#cat(' '                                           , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)

cat('This is the end'                              , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)
cat(' '                                            , file = R.file, sep=c("\n"), append = TRUE)
```

Here are the full contents of the recipient `R` file `my_R_file.R`:

```
This is my stuff
#
 
 
capture.output
  scenario  AA  BB  CC DD
1     3333 200 999 444  7
 
write.table
my.df <- read.table(text = '
scenario AA BB CC DD
3333 200 999 444 7
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 
This is the end
```

Here is the `warning` message returned by `write.table`:

```
Warning message:
In write.table(my.df, file = R.file, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,  :
  appending column names to file
```

Thank you for any suggestions on eliminating this `warning` message or arriving at a better solution.  I would rather not suppress all `warning` messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that there is `base:::print.data.frame` method involved when evaluating `my.df` which is of `class` `"data.frame"`. It has arguments such as `row.names=`. Accordingly you may specify:

```
capture.output(print(my.df, row.names=FALSE), file=R.file, append=TRUE)
```